# List Implementation and Custom Types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, list

I apologize in advance if this is vague...What is the best or most practical way to implement lists of custom types for MVVM?  I had someone tell me that for each type I have I should have corresponding List of it.  For example,  if I have a Customer class I should also have a CustomerList class whose base class is List and within this class I should do all my work on any list of Customers.

Since I am looking to start writing a couple applications using MVVM should each model contain a Customer and CustomerList class and then do I need a ViewModel for each of those Models?  I am just all sorts of confused and this seems to be overkill.

If someone could please explain this to me or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  I have look at quite a few MVVM videos and get the overall idea but some of this implementation I just haven't gotten yet.

Comment: What is the issue with `List<Customer>` or `ObservableCollection<Customer>` (or indeed `Collection<Customer>`, or `BindingList<Customer>`)?

Comment: I am just confused whether to have a property of List<Customers> or ObservableCollection<Customers> in Customers or to have a whole another class called Customers which is Customers : List<Customer> or Customers : ObservableCOllection<Customer>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your friend was talking about in needing a list for every class. I know some of the more common tutorials bind to ObservableCollections in their examples.

My suggestion is learn MVVM from tutorials, on your own, and then possibly teach your friend a little more about MVVM.

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739?tab=votes#tab-top) that will help you learn MVVM better.

Comment: I guess he wasn't strictly talking about MVVM and needing a list for every class, that was more when I was working with win forms.